# verifying download showing on screen for 12 hours and can't turn iPad off?

Tags: ipad

I tried to install the new apple update.  for 12 hours now the screen says "verifying update" and I can't even turn the iPad off?   it is plugged in.   Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Unplug it and do a 'hard restart' > note this is hard on your iPads hardware if you do this often, so only use this when needed.

Press and hold the sleep button while holding the home button until it shuts off and restarts. It should take no more than 10 seconds for it to recognize.